# Perforce: How to get the changelist numbers in revision graph?

Tags: perforce, p4v

For some reason, the changelist numbers are not showing up in Revision graph. How do I get it back? I did all the search but no luck. Any help is greatly appreaciated. I know this is not a coding question, but it would help my workflow to see them.
[image]

Comment: Looks like an OpenGL issue to me.  What version of P4V do you have?  Is there an option in its Preferences to use software rendering?

Comment: Rev. P4V/NTX64/2020.1/1966006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual glitches in Revision Graph are usually the result of OpenGL implementation issues.
Luckily, there's an easy workaround.  Locate the "software rendering" option in P4V's preferences and make sure it's enabled:

https://community.perforce.com/s/article/2900

(Hardware acceleration was necessary for decent antialiasing back in 2004 when Revision Graph was written, but on a modern laptop the performance difference should be negligible.)

Comment: I am using the latest P4V and the suggested options are not available anymore. https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r20.1/manuals/p4v/Content/P4V/configuring.preferences.tools.html The link which you posted seems to have dialogs from Windows95. I cannot find these options in latest P4V- Rev. P4V/NTX64/2020.1/1966006 /Windows10. Are there any other places to check these settings?

Comment: You may need to either find an older P4V release or raise a ticket with Perforce support.  I don't see where in the current release that option lives -- maybe it's hidden, or maybe there's a bug in the current release?  Your screenshot definitely indicates a rendering bug though -- apart from the missing changelist text, the numbers on the revisions are offset and slightly undersized, which suggests some kind of texture scaling issue.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot Samwise, I am able to figure it out. The issue was with Display Setting aspect ration. I changed it to different settings and I am able to see the numbers now.

Comment: Ah, might be that it's defaulting to software rendering and this is a Qt bug rather than an OpenGL bug then.  I know from (unfortunate) experience that Qt has a lot of issues with scaling text on high DPI displays...